# how can i use Progress Bar with Await code?

Tags: vb.net

Hi have button with Async Await command and
how can i use on my Await command with Progress Bar?

```
Private Async Sub Button1_ClickAsync(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTN_Clip_UP.Click
        Dim image = New InstaImage With {
                .Uri = Image_thumbnail
            }
        Dim video = New InstaVideo With {
            .Uri = Clip_Filename 'video file, only MP4 supported
        }
        Dim videoForUpload = New InstaVideoUpload With {
            .Video = video,
            .VideoThumbnail = image
        }
        Dim caption = RTB_CAP.Text.Trim
        Dim response = Await InstaApi.MediaProcessor.UploadVideoAsync(videoForUpload, caption)
        If response.Succeeded Then
            MessageBox.Show("Success", "Your Video successfully uploaded")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "error while sending image\r\n" + response.Info.Message)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: That's far too vague a description. You need to be specific about what you want to achieve. *"Use a ProgressBar"* doesn't mean much. It's simply a fancy way to display a ratio. For it to be useful, you need to be able to calculate that ratio. That's what you need to be working out how to do and, if you want our help, you have to explain what that ratio represents and what efforts you've made to calculate it.

Comment: In general, you use it the same way you'd use it if there were no `Await` in the code.  In this context, I presume you want `UploadVideoAsync` to be able to give you progress; in that case, I'd recommend reading the documentation to see what facilities they provide to support progress updates.